# How to display only date

Tags: php

```
$date_from1 = new DateTime('1-9-2016');                                 
$thisdate=$date_from1->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

when I  `print_r($thisdate);`

I am getting the output

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2016-09-02 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Australia/Sydney )
```

Expected Output:-

```
2016-09-02
```

Comment: echo explode(' ', $thisdate->date)[0];                                                       giving an error  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: $datedata = explode(' ', $thisdate->date);print_r($datedata);                              This is giving me the following output :Array ( [0] => )                                        And echo $thisdate->date is giving me this output:2016-09-02 00:00:00            I only want the date 2016-09-02 not 00:00:00

Comment: $datedata = explode('    ', $thisdate->date);
print_r($datedata);                                                                                             not working still getting output: Array ( [0] => )

Comment: I have added the space between the explode  still not working  i am still getting the output  Array ( [0] => )

Comment: using var_dump($thisdate->date); i am getting output as NULL

Comment: Should i convert that date object to string and then use str_replace so that i can only get the date?but i dont know how to convert that date object to string?

Answer (score 2):

You need to mention the date format.

Refer to the manual: [DateTime::format Example](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-examples)

```
echo $thisdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on date-time format manual:-  http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
<?php

$date_from1 = new DateTime('1-9-2016');                                 
$thisdate=$date_from1->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
//echo "<pre/>";print_r($thisdate);
echo $thisdate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output:-

https://eval.in/634751

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 $date_from1 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("1-9-2016"));
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.